# Javascript function to add onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop, pagination

I am creating a function in JS to create a pagination nav bar. It is suppose to get the total amount of pages and loop through that many times in order to create the proper divs and finally add an onclick function to each created div.

I managed to create the divs with no problem using the for 'i' value to add the ID and innerHTML for each, but the onclick function should also receive the same 'i' value but it won't. I changed the proper function for a simple console.log(i) because the issue is that instead of getting the proper 'i' value **the response is 3 in every button**. This is the code:

```
function create_pagination(totalPages, hasNext, hasPrevious) {
  if (document.querySelector('.page-number') != null) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.page-number').forEach((e) => e.remove());
  }

  for (i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++) {
    let previousDiv = document.querySelector('#hasPrevious');
    let nextDiv = document.querySelector('#hasNext');
    let parentDiv = document.querySelector('#pagination');

    if (hasPrevious) {
      previousDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (hasNext && hasPrevious === false) {
      nextDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }

    pageItemDiv = document.createElement('li');
    pageItemDiv.classList.add('page-item');
    pageItemDiv.classList.add('page-link');
    pageItemDiv.classList.add('page-number');

    pageItemNumber = document.createElement('a');
    pageItemNumber.id = `${i}`;
    pageItemNumber.innerHTML = `${i}`;
    pageItemNumber.onclick = () => console.log(i);

    pageItemDiv.appendChild(pageItemNumber);

    parentDiv.insertBefore(pageItemDiv, nextDiv);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: why did you repeat the sames `previousDiv`, `nextDiv`, `parentDiv` assignation in your loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic issue related to JavaScript 'closure' concept.

**Problem**

In your loop `for (i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++)`, the variable `i` is bound to the same variable, and after the loop `i = 3`, thus, when triggering `onclick` the variable `i` is bound to value 3, and leads to '3 in every button'.

[This article](http://conceptf1.blogspot.com/2013/11/javascript-closures.html) may help you understand the problem as well.

**Simple ES6 fix**

We only need to use `let`/`const` keyword in the loop condition. Check `create_pagination_fix1` in the code below.

Reason: [docs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation) In `for(const i;;){}` or `for(let i;;){}`, `i` can get a new binding for every iteration of the loop, as each iteration is a new lexical scope. If you use `var` as `for (i = 1` is equal to `for (var i = 1`, `i` would get the same binding when you click the button later.

**Fix using closure**

Please check `create_pagination_fix2` in the code below. There have been many posts about the usage of JavaScript closure in the loop, I'd refer you to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for a nice explanation.

You can run the code snippet below and see the difference between each method. My changes are quite little.

```js
var pageItemDiv = document.getElementById("app");

function create_pagination_problematic(totalPages, hasNext, hasPrevious) {
  if (document.querySelector(".page-number") != null) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".page-number").forEach((e) => e.remove());
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++) {
    var pageItemNumber = document.createElement("button");
    pageItemNumber.id = `${i}`;
    pageItemNumber.innerHTML = `${i}`;
    pageItemNumber.onclick = () => console.log(i);

    pageItemDiv.appendChild(pageItemNumber);
  }
}

function create_pagination_fix1(totalPages, hasNext, hasPrevious) {
  if (document.querySelector(".page-number") != null) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".page-number").forEach((e) => e.remove());
  }

  // only change is here, use let instead of var
  for (let i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++) {
    var pageItemNumber = document.createElement("button");
    pageItemNumber.id = `${i}`;
    pageItemNumber.innerHTML = `${i}`;
    pageItemNumber.onclick = () => console.log(i);

    pageItemDiv.appendChild(pageItemNumber);
  }
}

function getOnclick(i) {
  return function () {
    console.log("Onclick: " + i);
  };
}

function create_pagination_fix2(totalPages, hasNext, hasPrevious) {
  if (document.querySelector(".page-number") != null) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".page-number").forEach((e) => e.remove());
  }

  for (var i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++) {
    var pageItemNumber = document.createElement("button");
    pageItemNumber.id = `${i}`;
    pageItemNumber.innerHTML = `${i}`;
    // only changing here: use closure to keep reference to value i
    pageItemNumber.onclick = getOnclick(i);

    pageItemDiv.appendChild(pageItemNumber);
  }
}

create_pagination_problematic(3);
pageItemDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
pageItemDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
create_pagination_fix1(3);
pageItemDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
pageItemDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
create_pagination_fix2(3);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>
      First row is wrong implementation, when second and third rows are fix.
    </p>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

just change

```
for (i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++) {
```

to

```
for (let i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++) {
```

your code (cleanned)

```js
create_pagination(4, false, false)

function create_pagination(totalPages, hasNext, hasPrevious)
  {
  document.querySelectorAll('.page-number').forEach(el => el.remove())

  let previousDiv = document.querySelector('#hasPrevious')
    , nextDiv     = document.querySelector('#hasNext')
    , parentDiv   = document.querySelector('#pagination')
    ;
  if (hasPrevious)   previousDiv.style.display = 'block'
  else if (hasNext)  nextDiv.style.display     = 'block'
    ;
  for (let pageN = 1; pageN < totalPages +1; ++pageN) 
    {
    pageItemDiv    = document.createElement('li')
    pageItemNumber = document.createElement('a')

    pageItemDiv.className      = 'page-item page-link page-number'
    pageItemNumber.id          = 
    pageItemNumber.textContent = `${pageN}`
      ;
    pageItemNumber.onclick = () => {console.clear(); console.log(pageN) }

    pageItemDiv.appendChild(pageItemNumber);
    parentDiv.insertBefore(pageItemDiv, nextDiv);
    }
  }
```

```css
#pagination li { margin: .5em 0;}
#pagination a { display: block; width: 3em; background-color: lightblue;}
```

```html
<ul id="pagination"></ul>
```